# Modular approach for ruby on rails (ror)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new on ruby on rails.

I have a project based on three kind of roles (admin,supplier,customer). I have all the understanding of business logic which will go behind it. But I don't know how to keep code separated. Is there any modular approach we can follow in rails to do anything we want to do with different roles e.g. Admin, Supplier, Customer **SEPERATEDLY**

Comment: Did you checkout CanCan - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan ?

Comment: You could use modules to namespace the different concerns.

Comment: @kiddorails

Just checked. Well it solves a minimum of my concern. I also need to separate the code after the role authentication.

Comment: @spickermaan

Can you please elaborate more on that? I didn't get your point.

Comment: Thanks  splicker. 

I got your point. This will surely solve my problem.